# Crystal Reports - displaying multivariate parameter in details section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to display an array of text in a Crystal Reports document in the details section but I only get 1 row of the first array which I send using the .ToArray() function - these values are shown but my section doesn't extend by rows. I suspect this is my fault with the details section options, but I have wasted a lot of time trying to find the cause. Would anyone be able to help?

```
List<string> arrayList = new List<string>();
report.Load(path);
report.SetParameterValue("name", arrayList.ToArray());
```

[displaying parameter values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M4dQ.png)
[raport result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIWCn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Join() function in a Crystal formula to "flatten" the parameter:

```
Join({?your_parameter_name}, ", ")
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, because if I send more parameters than the area intended for this, they aren't visible. I would need something like "grouping" while using the database, but I'm just passing parameters to the document, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

To stack the values vertically, change the expression to:

```
Join({?your_parameter_name}, Chr(10))
```

Right-click the formula field on the report canvas, select 'Format Field...',
Go to 'Common' tab, and turn on the 'Can Grow' checkbox.